# Subnet is big enough but no connection between two servers (within IPSec vpn)

Tags: networking, vpn, router, ipsec, route

I could bet that everything is set up correctly. But it doesnt work :-(

[image]

As you can see the network is quite simple. - I hope.

My goal is a connection between Server 2 and Server 4.
On Server 2 there is a MySQL server and I will access them from Server 4.

The problem is that I can make a ping from Server 4 to the Router 1 or to Server 1 - but not to Server 2.
The subnet is big enough so it reachs from 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.15.254. So normally I expect that the Server 3 can do anything in the other network.

Server 2 can ping server 3 and server 3 can ping server 2.
And Router 1 can ping Server 2 and server 3, too.

Here are some informations about the routes. But I'm sure they are mostly correct.

**Server 4 Routes:**

[image]

**Router 2 IPSec:**

[image]

**Server 4 Traceroute to Router 1:**

[image]

**Server 4 Traceroute to Server 2:**

[image]

Thanks in Advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that Server 2 has no default gateway set. When it receives a TCP SYN from 172.16.1.125, it has no route back to this server.

Your traceroute result from server 4 to server 2 is weird, but based on the fact that it sees server 2 as the second hop, not the third, your router 1 must be doing some sort of proxying.

Comment: Hmm I tought the router does this via NAT? So that the device can send the packages in local network and the router knows that it should forward the packages via NAT to the IPSec server.

Comment: The router may well do NAT, but it probably (can't tell for sure without your config) is only NATing server 2's address, not server 4's. So Server 2 receives a ping packet from 172.16.1.x (probably 254, but again config dependent)...when it tries to reply, this address is not in its network, and it has no gateway, so it has no place to send it. If this is the case, from server 2, if you try to ping anything in 172.16.1.x, you should get a "No route to host" error.